# ldapjs error in server.js

Tags: node.js

I received this error:

```
/home/user/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/server.js:65
throw new TypeError('Invalid argument type: ' + typeof (argv[i]));
        ^
TypeError: Invalid argument type: undefined
at mergeFunctionArgs (/home/user/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/server.js:65:13)
at Server._mount (/home/user/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/server.js:814:35)
at Server.add (/home/user/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/server.js:500:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/workspace/ldap/ldap.js:34:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

when attempting to do the tests on [ldapjs guide](http://ldapjs.org/guide.html).

This error pretty much blocks on doing further testing since the service won't start.

Comment: Tried to "fix" the server.js, but for some reason it fails to parse the mentioned row correctly. It always gives the same error, even when attempting to make the error a variable and throw it later.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 11.10, the ldapjs was installed with 'npm install ldapjs'

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: The code is the same than provided in the example [ldapjs guide](http://ldapjs.org/guide.html)

Comment: The guide has a lot of snippets, please be more specific

Comment: I refer to 'server.js' installed with npm (to be more specific). I don't think it has anything to do with the example code given in the guide I linked (just a link to show what I have been working on). The example does not refer to this file. The 'server.js' is installed by the npm in '/home/user/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/server.js'... Basically you take "any code" in that example that includes starting the server.

Comment: I mean this error comes from wrong use of the API (passing undefined instead of a function somewhere) so that's why I need to see all your custom code that is causing this error

Comment: Ok, sorry I miss understood your question. Here's a link to the code I currently have. http://pastebin.com/tMnYUUmH

Comment: Finally :D I spotted the error immediately :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19320/discussion-between-ville-myrskyneva-and-esailija)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `pre` to ldapjs before it has been assigned the array of functions (I.E. it is `undefined` at the time). Variable and functions declarations are hoisted to the top, but *assignments* are not.

Move this

```
133. var pre = [authorize, loadPasswdFile];
```

To the top, or at least before you pass it to ldapjs.

The assignment is currently happening on line 133, but you are already passing it on line 34:

```
34. server.add('ou=users, o=myhost', pre, function(req, res, next)
```

Btw, you should be able to see better where errors originate from by setting this at the start of the code:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
```

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" was to comment out the line whole together. It surely is not the right way to have it fixed, but at least the service starts then.

Comment: If someone knows a better way to do this, please add the correct answer.